# Testing mongocxx c++ driver with a sample code

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I'm trying to connect mongdb with mongocxx driver in my C++ sample code. I added Additional include, Libraries  and dependencies. When I build it it shows following error.

this is the full code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>

using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);

    return 0;
}
thi
```

s is the error output.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 10 unresolved externals MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\x64\Release\MongoCTest1.exe   1   
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_array::type_id" may not be initialized   MongoCTest1 c:\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   181 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_binary::type_id" may not be initialized  MongoCTest1 c:\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   206 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_bool::type_id" may not be initialized    MongoCTest1 c:\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   264 
Error (active)  E0145   member "bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_code::type_id" may not be initialized    MongoCTest1 c:\mongo-cxx-driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\types.hpp   421 
Error (active)  E0145   member C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::instance(void)" (__imp_??0instance@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@XZ)    MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::~instance(void)" (__imp_??1instance@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@XZ)   MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client::client(void)" (__imp_??0client@options@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@XZ) MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::options::client::~client(void)" (__imp_??1client@options@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@XZ)    MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::uri(class bsoncxx::v_noabi::string::view_or_value)" (__imp_??0uri@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@Vview_or_value@string@1bsoncxx@@@Z)  MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl mongocxx::v_noabi::uri::~uri(void)" (__imp_??1uri@v_noabi@mongocxx@@QEAA@XZ)  MongoCTest1 C:\Users\Nuwanst\source\repos\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1\MongoCTest1.obj   1
```

Comment: [Much better than your previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753187/mongocxx-driver-testing-error-with-c-code). But you really ought to either edit this into the original, or remove the poorly asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says what it says initialized your driver first. if you have compiled your driver correctly these codes must be working.

```
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
   #include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
   #include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
   #include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
   #include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>


   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
   using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;
   mongocxx::instance instance{};// don't put inside main 

int main() {
mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{ "mongodb://localhost:27017" } };
auto coll = conn["test"]["coll"];
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};
document << "Data" << "hello";
coll.insert_one(document.view());

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this [example](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.4.0/examples_2mongocxx_2client_session_8cpp-example.html), the driver is initiated inside main.